# Black screen after resuming suspension - iMac 2011, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, grub

newbie question here.

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an old iMac 2011 (unless I'm mistaken, the graphic card is ATI Radeon HD 4670).

I encountered the issue of a black screen during the boot sequence, which I could solve by adding `"nomodeset"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`

Now, the problem is that, if I try to suspend the computer, when resuming from suspension, I am faced with the same black screen and nothing seems able to get me out of it. It seems to be a graphic card problem because the fan of the computer resumes working and, if I open a console by pressing ALT+F3, type in my login and password and then `sudo reboot` (+ password) - all this blindly since the screen remains blank -, then the computer effectively reboots.

As suggested on some forums, I tried to also add `"nomodeset"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` but this did not help. As a side note, I do not even properly understand why it could help : why would grub be called after resuming from suspension?

For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that I do not necessarily need to suspend the computer; the only thing that matters to me is to be able to switch off the screen (by contrast to the blank screen of idle mode, where the screen is still on and still warm). Any alternative to suspension, or any clue to solve the blank screen issue, would be most welcome.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this is not the answer usually expected - I'm using Ubuntu on imac 2011 for few long years now, and it always was a headache with power, screen dimming and few other things, like gnome-shell hanging.

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 20 - under KDE I don't have the problem you're experiencing. It goes to sleep and resumes without any issues. Try KDE?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may try again, though installing KDE on top of Ubuntu aleady caused its lot of problems (had to reinstall Dropbox, Back in time and other things). Too bad I did not try the suspend/resume before uninstalling KDE. May I ask you if you are using any particular in option in `/etc/default/grub` ?

Comment: hi @GlassSignal sorry for replying after such a long while. I did not use any grub options. It has it's moments of failure though (sometimes can't wake up still, but very rarely).